# How to compile a DPDK application as a library

Tags: dpdk

I have a program using DPDK and I am compiling it using the Makefile provided in the examples.

If i compile the program as an APP (as describe [here](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides-18.02/prog_guide/build_app.html)), all goes
well.
However, my code is part of a larger project, for which the use of a
separate makefile causes a lot of troubles.
So I bundled my code in a library, as described in the same page.

The program that calls the functions in the library (to initialize the
EAL) is getting this error:

```
MBUF: error setting mempool handler
Cannot init mbuf pool
```

It seems that, when the application is compiled as a library, the EAL cannot be initialized correctly.

I report here the steps to reproduce the problem using the l2fwd example.

**Background**

I built DPDK from source as described [here](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/build_dpdk.html), and I have one ethernet interface bound to DPDK drivers:

```
$ $RTE_SDK/usertools/dpdk-devbind.py --status |head -n4
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:01:00.0 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection 10fb' drv=igb_uio unused=ixgbe
```

**Run the *l2fwd* example**

Copy the example folder first and then run the example:

```
$ cp -r $RTE_SDK/examples/l2fwd $RTE_SDK/examples/l2fwd-lib/
$ cd $RTE_SDK/examples/l2fwd

$ make
CC main.o
LD l2fwd
INSTALL-APP l2fwd
INSTALL-MAP l2fwd.map

$ sudo ./build/l2fwd -l 0-3  -- -p 0x1
Port statistics ====================================
Statistics for port 0 ------------------------------
Packets sent:                        0
Packets received:                    0
Packets dropped:                     0
Aggregate statistics ===============================
Total packets sent:                  0
Total packets received:              0
Total packets dropped:               0
====================================================
```

- It works!

**Build the same example as a library**

- ```
  cd ../l2fwd-lib/
  mv main.c l2fwd.c
  ```
- Modify l2fwd.c, adding `#include "l2fwd.h"` on top and replacing

  ```
  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  ```

  with

  ```
  int start(int argc, char **argv)
  ```
- Create the header file l2fwd.h with the library interface:

  ```
  int start(int argc, char **argv);
  ```
- Modify the Makefile as described in the docs:

  ```
  APP = l2fwd      --->   LIB = libl2fwd.a
  SRCS-y := main.c --->   SRCS-y := l2fwd.c
  include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.extapp.mk   --->   include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.extlib.mk
  ```
- Compile the library:

  ```
  $ make
  CC l2fwd.o
  AR libl2fwd.a
  INSTALL-LIB libl2fwd.a
  ```
- Write a program that uses the library. Create the `main.c` file with just these 2 lines:

  ```
  #include "l2fwd.h"
  int main (int argc, char **argv) { start(argc, argv); }
  ```
- compile it (with all the needed libraries):

  ```
  gcc -L build/lib/ -L $RTE_SDK/build/lib/ main.c -o main.o -l l2fwd -l dpdk -l numa -pthread -l dl
  ```
- Finally, run it with the same parameters used earlier:

  ```
  $ sudo ./main.o -l 0-3  -- -p 0x1
  EAL: Detected 40 lcore(s)
  EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
  EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
  EAL: Probing VFIO support...
  MAC updating enabled
  EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
    Cause: No Ethernet ports - bye
  ```

In this case, the EAL cannot be initialized properly (the ethernet port is still bound to the DPDK drivers).

**Edit 1**

According to @Andriy Berestovskyy, the linker `--whole-archive` option is needed when linking DPDK libraries. This solves the problem with the examples. 
However, my program is facing a different problem now. I need to use a custom build system, so I am linking the DPDK application as a library. During execution I get the error:

```
MBUF: error setting mempool handler
mempool/dpaa2: Not a valid dpaa2 buffer pool
```

Looks like it is using the dpaa2 driver, that is the wrong driver (my NIC is using igb_uio). Any hints on why this is happening? The same code worked when compiled as a DPDK app, so it is probably related to the linking process.

**Edit 2**

This error is due to the fact that I compiled DPDK with the 
`CONFIG_RTE_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=y` option. When DPDK is built as a shared library, the driver must be explicitly set using the `-d` EAL command line option. 
I re-compiled DPDK with `CONFIG_RTE_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=n` and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> compile it (with all the needed libraries):
>
> ```
> gcc -L build/lib/ -L $RTE_SDK/build/lib/ main.c -o main.o -l l2fwd -l dpdk -l numa -pthread -l dl
> ```

I guess the issue is in this step. DPDK uses link-level constructors (i.e. `__attribute__((constructor))`). See the definition of `RTE_INIT()` for example. Also there are callbacks etc. etc.

So to properly link with DPDK we have to:

- either use an `rte.app.mk` in the Makefile (see [Development Kit Build System](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/dev_kit_build_system.html))
- or in case we need to use a custom build system, we need to link DPDK libraries after the `--whole-archive` option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solves the problem with the example. I guess why they don't mention it in the docs. However, my program is showing a different error. See edited post.

Comment: @Amedeo There are few options: 1) blacklist the DPAA2 device if you have it in the system 2) disable DPAA2 in the config 3) define user mempool ops, which will have a higher precedence over platform ops.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem was that I was compiling DPDK with CONFIG_RTE_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=y, in which case the driver must be explicitly set with the '-d' EAL option.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue and as mentioned in [here](https://github.com/zrlio/urdma), I used `-d` option to link the libray "`-d /usr/lib64/librte_mempool_ring.so`". It worked.